# Not able to understand why computed doesn't work without watch

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, toast, inertiajs

The following code of inertiajs with vue only works this way

```
computed: {
        flash: function () {
            if (this.$page.props.flash.message) {
                this.$toast.open({
                    type: this.$page.props.flash.type,
                    message: this.$page.props.flash.message.message,
                })
            }
            return this.$page.props.flash.message
        }
    },
    watch: {
        flash: function (newVal, oldVal) {
        }
    },
```

but if i remove the watch part, it doesn't work. Also if i put the toast part inside watch, it doesn't work. Anyone facing same issue? I am working with inertiajs on laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
computed: {
    flash(){
        if (this.$page.props.flash.message) {
            this.$toast.open({
                type: this.$page.props.flash.type,
                message: this.$page.props.flash.message.message,
            })
        }
        return this.$page.props.flash.message
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately for me, your answer is not working.